# minimum/maximum of the linear function $f(x,y)=ax+by$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-programming

Suppose that the function $f(x,y)=ax+by$, $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$ defined on a closed and bounded set $\mathcal{D}$. Since $(\vec{\nabla}f)(x,y)=(a,b)\neq(0,0)$, the extremum points are on the boundary of $\mathcal{D}$.

My question regards the case $\mathcal{D}$ is a polygon: A basic result in Linear Programming asserts that $f$ get it extremum points on the vertices if $\mathcal{D}$ is $\mathbf{convex}$ (as I read in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Is that result true also for non-convex polygon?

My attempt: Every polygon can be divided to convex polygons (e.g., if $ABCD$ is a non-convex quadrilateral with vertices $A(0,0)$, $B(3,0)$, $C(1,1)$, $D(0,3)$, then $ABCD$ can be divided into two convex triangles, namely $ABC$ and $ACD$). By applying the basic result for each of these convex polygons, it follows that the extremum. Is this argument correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article *immediately* restricts its interest to convex polytopes. Hence it is not surprising it doesnÄt say anything about the location of extrema on non-convex polytopes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the fact that every polygon (not to mention higher polytopes) can be divided into convex polygons. Interestingly, it would be a not as trivial as you think exercise to formally prove this fact (or the essential step: "Every non-convex polygon has an interior diagonal").

But we can simply prove the claim about the maximum occuring in a vertex in a different way, namely by induction on the dimension:
You already know that there is a point $p\in\partial \mathcal D$ with $f(p)=\max_{x\in\mathcal D}f(x)$.
But for a polytope, $\partial D$ consists of several lower-dimensional polytopes. So if $\mathcal F$ is the "face" of $\mathcal D$ containing $p$, we know by induction hypothesis that there is a vertex $q$ of $\mathcal F$ with $f(q)=\max_{x\in\mathcal F}f(x)=\max_{x\in\mathcal D}f(x)$. But of course $q$ is also a vertex of $\mathcal D$!

Comment: Thank @Hagen! but why the theorem I mentioned in Linear programming need to assume that the region is convex? Is the proof of that result depend upon that in any way?